# Can the submodules use the reactor as parent in Maven?

Tags: java, maven, minecraft

Hello Stackoverflow community,

i recently started working with maven to see what is possible or better to see if its easier to have a dependency manager or including everything to your own.

### Basic Informations

**Repository**

https://github.com/JXCoding/MavenTests

**Reactor**

```
<groupId>de.jxson.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenTests</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>API</module>
    <module>v1_18_R1</module>
</modules>
```

**submodule API**

```
<parent>
  <artifactId>MavenTests</artifactId>
  <groupId>de.jxson.maven</groupId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>API</artifactId>

<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
```

Which depends of reactor as parent

**submodule v1_18_R1**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>MavenTests</artifactId>
    <groupId>de.jxson.maven</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>v1_18_R1</artifactId>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>de.jxson.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>API</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Which depends of API and reactor as parent

### My Problem is:

When I build with `mvn clean package`, there is an error on my module v1_18_R1 in which a class from API is not found.

### Questions:

Why a class is not found if the required dependency is already added?

Comment: Can you please make an example project on github....

Comment: Of course here: https://github.com/JXCoding/MavenTests

Comment: share us the exact used commands, also your os, java and maven version. You project has several errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usually** [maven reactor](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) is used for:

- Collects all the available modules to build
- Sorts the projects into the correct build order
- Builds the selected projects in order

**And not to be as parent of another projects**. If you need to centralize libraries , versions, etc create a extra project with `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

### Solution

- Remove the **parent** from your submodules
- Add this to all of your submodules which requires spigot jars

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>elmakers-repo</id>
      <url>https://maven.elmakers.com/repository/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

WIth these fixes, I was able to build your git repository with `mvn clean package`

[image]

### Spigot notes

- offical git repository don't build https://hub.spigotmc.org/stash/projects/SPIGOT
- Official repository don't works: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-maven/
- Only this repository works https://maven.elmakers.com/repository/org/spigotmc/spigot/

Comment: I had taken your tips and managed to get it working. Somehow it got out of sync aswell. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't forget check the upper arrow if this was useful for you

Comment: I tried it, but it says: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." i am sorry :/

Comment: Ohh :(  Help someone to get more points :)